# jQuery UI Datepicker prevent blur event on date select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having a jQuery UI Datepicker and use it for inline edit i.e. I initially show dates as label and on click of it replace by editable date picker and on select, I do 2 things;
a) set the selected date in model (and do some validations in my changeAction method) and
b) replace the date textbox with label (to display selected date)

My question is how do I prevent blur event when any date is selected? I want the blur event to be fired only if the user does not select any date and just clicks out.

Below is my code;

```
$(document).on("change", ".datePicker", function () {
    var dataValid = $(this).attr('data-valid');
    if (dataValid == "Y") {
        var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
        var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
        var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableDateTxt','name':currElmModelAttr, 'data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':currElmModelId,'html':$(this).val()});
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.append(divEle);
        $(this).remove();
    }
});


$(document).on("blur",".datePicker", function () {
    if (this.hasAttribute('data-model-id')) {
        var dataValid = $(this).attr('data-valid');

        if (typeof dataValid == "undefined" || dataValid == "Y") {
            var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
            var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
            var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableDateTxt','name':currElmModelAttr, 'data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':currElmModelId,'html':$(this).val()});
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.append(divEle);
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        }
    }   
});

changeAction: function (event) {
    var self = this;
// my custom code to set the date in model and do some validations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On "change" event add data-previouse-event = "changed"

```
$(document).on("change", ".datePicker", function () {
var dataValid = $(this).attr('data-valid');
if (dataValid == "Y") {
    var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableDateTxt','name':currElmModelAttr, 'data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':currElmModelId,'html':$(this).val()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(divEle);
    $(this).remove();
}

$(this).data("previous-fired-event", "change");
});
```

If blur event call earlier then change, add register callback before blur event in jQuery. 
It is easy to do, i thinck u managed with this yourself.

Then on blur event add:

```
$(document).on("blur",".datePicker", function () {
if ($(this).data("previous-fired-event") === "change")
  return;

  $(this).data("previous-fired-event", "blur");

if (this.hasAttribute('data-model-id')) {
    var dataValid = $(this).attr('data-valid');

    if (typeof dataValid == "undefined" || dataValid == "Y") {
        var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
        var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
        var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableDateTxt','name':currElmModelAttr, 'data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':currElmModelId,'html':$(this).val()});
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.append(divEle);
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
    }
}   
});
```